# Programmatically retrieve per tag network usage data on Android

Tags: android, performance, sockets, networking

TrafficStats allows us to tag specific network socket usages by using
setThreadStatsTag, tagSocket(), untagSocket().

We can also visualise the network traffic per tag using the Network Traffic tool (DDMS) in the lab.

I am wondering how to do this in the field. Is there a programmatic way to retrieve the per tag network traffic (something that Network Traffic tool relies on), which I can leverage.

My specific use case is to understand the data usage for the various modules in my app. I am hoping to tag the sockets based on module, and to retrieve the per tag data usage and report it to server daily via our analytics pipeline.

If tagging does not work for me, what other options have folks explored that you believe can help. Thanks in advance.